# DateTime set TimeZone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

ubuntu 14.04
ruby 1.9.3-p484
rails 3.2.18

I have a date as a string: `06/20/2015 02:45 AM`

```
d = DateTime.strptime('06/20/2015 02:45 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p').to_time
=> Sat, 20 Jun 2015 02:45:00 UTC
```

Current TimeZone may be different and placed in `Time.zone`.

I tried `d.to_time.in_time_zone`. It gives respectively for PDT and CDT TimeZone:

```
Fri, 19 Jun 2015 21:45:00 CDT -05:00
Fri, 19 Jun 2015 19:45:00 PDT -07:00
```

I need to get DateTime object that holds date `Sat, 20 Jun 2015 02:45:00 PDT -07:00` for PDT zone or `Sat, 20 Jun 2015 02:45:00 CDT -05:00` for CDT zone.

Comment: when I run your DateTime code I don't get it back in UTC:  `2015-06-19 22:45:00 -0400`  -- care to share version of ruby & rails?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work:

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Central Time (US & Canada)")
d.to_time.in_time_zone.in_time_zone(zone)
```

or just

```
d.to_time.in_time_zone.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. d.to_time.in_time_zone.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") => Fri, 19 Jun 2015 19:45:00 PDT -07:00

Comment: neither did the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#config/application.rb
 config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)' 
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Don't forget to restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Method `DateTime#offset` rules:

```
d = DateTime.strptime('06/20/2015 02:45 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d = d.change(offset: (Time.zone.now.utc_offset / 3600).to_s)
```